# Select value from database based on dropdownlist value

Tags: c#

I have database table `leave_rec(name,date1,leave,ltype)`, a `Dropdown list` and a `gridview`.

I want to do such that,when I select month(e.g. february) in dropdown list the gridview should display all table values for february `only(e.g.rohan leuva,2/28/2013,full,casual)`,means record which has month=2 (february).

How to overcome this issue? I tried but I can only display all the values in `gridview` at this moment. Any help would be greatly appriciated.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["leave"].ConnectionString;
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select date1,leave,ltype from leave_rec where name='" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "'", conn);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
GridView1.DataSource = ds;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

The above code displays the `date1`,`leave`,`ltype` for `dropdownlist1.selectedvalue.` But now i want to have second dropdown in which months will be there. so when i select february in second one, grid should display value for dropdownlist1.selectedvalue for february only.

Comment: watch out for SQL Injection

Comment: i am not getting you?how sql injection can be helpful to me in this regard?

Comment: in dropdown what you have?

Answer (score 1):

First, your query needs to be something like this:

```
select date1, leave, ltype from leave_rec where MONTH(date1) = 2 // February
```

Then, integrating it into your code:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select date1, leave, ltype from leave_rec where MONTH(date1) = @p1", conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("p1", combo.SelectedKey));
```

Use parameters instead of string concatenation to avoid SQL Injection, see an example here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter

(Use your own control names for "combo.SelectedKey", of course)

Comment: Thanks alot....this is working exactly what i want...the esiest and quick way too...thanks again...how to upvote this answer?

Comment: You can upvote the answer with the up arrow at the left of the answer, and you should also mark it as the right one so the question appears as answered.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem in query , instead of name you have to write date1

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select date1, leave, ltype from leave_rec where MONTH(date1) ='" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "'", conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the dataset to DataTable 
then - Filter it by dt.Filter=monthName.toString()
then bind it to GridView - dt.DefaultView;

Answer (score -1):

Agree with @Saurabh, look into the use of Linq and Stored Procedures to force the use of types and modelling.